# SQL Group By to count records for groups of data

Tags: sql, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have a database with chemistry data. My fields are Site, Date, and Analyte. Samples are collected every few days, and samples may be tested for nitrate, nitrite, or phosphorus. But all three tests are not done on all days; some days, only one or two tests are done.

I want to count the instances where all three tests are done. I have simple aggregate function:

```
Select site, date, analyte
from myTable
group by site, date, analyte
order by site, date, analyte
```

But this isn't right. I want to return only sets of data where all three tests were done at a station on a day (ie, complete data sets). I just want a total count of the dates on which all three tests were done.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Sample data would be a big help.  How do you know what something is tested for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for complete data sets by site/date, then I think you want:

```
select site, date
from mytable
where analyte in ('nitrate', 'nitrite', 'phosphorus')  -- may not be necessary
group by site, date
having count(distinct analyte) = 3;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can check that there are 3 records available for each `(site, date, analyte)` tuple by adding a `having` clause to the existing query:

```
select site, date, analyte
from myTable
group by site, date, analyte
having count(*) = 3
order by site, date, analyte
```